# Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values when using descdist function

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset with 33 variables and 1084 observations. Right now I want to build a model. In order to do so, I want to use the descdist function from the fitdistrplus package in order to see which distribution fits my model best.
My dependent variable looks as follows:

```
1   15.0
2   5.0
3   5.0
4   NA
5   NA
6   100.0
7   5.0
8   10.0
9   50.0
10  240.0
11  20.5
12  NA
13  0
14  NA
15  60.0
16  NA
17  5.0
18  5.0
19  25.0
20  20.0
21  50.0
22  75.0
23  NA
24  10.0
```

I am runnig the following command:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(MASS)
library(logspline)
descdist(mydata$var1, discrete = FALSE)
```

But I am getting this error message and no plot:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
```

I do have a couple of missing values (NA) and some zeros (0) but there are a lot of other observations which are not 0 or missing.I do not have negative values. 
Can someone help me understand the error message and possibly help me fix the problem?

That would be great!

Best
Anca

Comment: @StupidWolf, thank you so much for editing this. Very kind of you!

Comment: no problem.. so that we can read it.. hope you dun mind. i can answer your question below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the missing data, using your table above:

```
mydata = structure(list(var1 = c(15, 5, 5, NA, NA, 100, 5, 10, 50, 240, 
20.5, NA, 0, NA, 60, NA, 5, 5, 25, 20, 50, 75, NA, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
24L))

library(fitdistrplus)
library(MASS)
library(logspline)
descdist(mydata$var1, discrete = FALSE)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
```

Try this:

```
descdist(mydata[complete.cases(mydata),"var1"], discrete = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: et voilá it works! Thank you so much, you made my life so much easier! :)

Comment: @StupidWolf I have the same issue as Anca but your solution doesn't work for me - it gives me an error that says, 'data must be a numeric vector'. I have checked that my dependent variable is a numeric class so I'm not sure what might be causing this - any ideas?

Comment: @milsandhills, I cannot tell. Maybe try `descdist(na.omit(mydata$var1), discrete = FALSE)`, basically you need to remove the NAs from your vector